# Getting an error with dynamic SQL statement trying to create a database, user, and login

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a single stored procedure that:
1. Create a database
2. Create a login
3. Create a user
4. Assign the user to the login
5. Make the login SA (sysadmin role)

I am trying to create this stored procedure with 3 parameters. The first parameter is the name of the login. The second parameter is the name of the user. The third parameter is the password for the login. (The database name is the same as the user) When I only have two parameters, the user and the password (with the database name and the login name the same as the user name), it works fine without any errors.

```
USE []
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spCreateDatabases]    Script Date: 11/8/2018 1:54:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateDatabaseWithSAUserAndLoginx]
    @userID varchar(50),
    @password varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @newdb sysname
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @newdb = @userID
    PRINT @UserID
    EXEC('CREATE DATABASE ' + @newdb)
END
BEGIN
    -- Create the user name
    SET @SQL = 'USE ' + @newdb + ';' + 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @userID + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @password + '''; ' + 
    'CREATE USER ' + @userID + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @userID + '; ' + 'ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER ' + @userID + ';'         
    EXECUTE(@SQL);
END
```

However, when I add the new parameter, it gives me the error message: Cannot add the server principal ' ', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

```
USE []
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spCreateDatabases]    Script Date: 11/8/2018 1:54:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateDatabaseWithSAUserAndLoginx]
    @userID varchar(50),
    @login varchar (50),
    @password varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @newdb sysname
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @newdb = @userID
    EXEC('CREATE DATABASE ' + @newdb)
END
BEGIN
    -- Create the user name
    SET @SQL = 'USE ' + @newdb + ';' + 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @login + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @password + '''; ' + 
    'CREATE USER ' + @userID + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @login + '; ' + 'ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER ' + @userID + ';'         
    EXECUTE(@SQL);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `ALTER SERVER ROLE xxx ADD MEMBER`, use @login instead of @userid

...

> ADD MEMBER server_principal Adds the specified server principal to the
>   server role. server_principal can be a login or a user-defined server
>   role. server_principal cannot be a fixed server role, a database role,
>   or sa.